# Using a display method with local variables in java

Tags: java

So I have to write a program for an invoice where I define the variables locally, instead of globally. So it kinda looks like this the way I have it.

```
public void setAmount(int anyAmount)
{ 
int amount;
amount = anyAmount;
}
```

I then do the display method like this and get an error saying cannot find symbol

```
public void displayInvoice()
{
System.out.println("Amount: " + amount);
```

I can easily do this globally, but having troubles with this. Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you read the task correctly?

Comment: you should declare amount as class level variable and then set it and get its resuls

Comment: Is the requirement that variables be defined locally part of a homework assignment?

Comment: @nsgulliver isn't that as global as it gets in Java?

Comment: It is for an assignment, for some reason he wants us to do it locally instead. We have done others with a global variable, but I guess not this time. The actually question in the book does not care, but during the instructions he added saying not to define globallly

Comment: Or you could pass the amount in as a parameter to displayInvoice?

Comment: @James i might be mixing with other language but point is the same, isn't?

Comment: @nsgulliver aim under the impression that that's what he's doing when he says he can do it globally. He wants another way

Comment: @James, the way he is trying won't work because of scope

Comment: When you say you cannot do it globally, do you mean that you can not store the vars at the class level? Or that you cannot define public static vars to hold the data? The current code in your example will not work.

Comment: Declare it locally inside the main function, and pass it along to all the other required functions as you need them. Main never goes out of scope until the application closes (usually), and you can then just pass the value around. Throw in a while loop, and you can just keep entering values. That's probably what the teacher is after.

Answer (score 3):

When you declare a variable inside a function, such as in your setAmount, it only exists for as long as that function is executing; it only exists between the { and }. That's why you're unable to reference it later in the second function, as it no longer exists. Essentially, what you're doing is setting it, and then getting rid of it right away, through no effort on your code, but simply through the way memory is allocated and used in programs.

The way to get around this would be to use a "global" as you've said, or to pass it back after you set it, and put it into another variable, which you then send to your displayInvoice function. The last method requires that the setAmount and displayInvoice are part of a larger function themselves, and the intermediary variable is declared inside it. Over all, a "global" as you've said, is the easiest and probably best solution given what you've explained.

Unworking Example:

```
main() {
   int amount = 0;
   amount = setAmount(5);
   displayInvoice(amount);
}
```

In doing so though, you may as well forgo the setAmount function, as you can see it's fairly redundant. Keeping set amount, you'd need to change it to

```
Public int setAmount(int anyAmount)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a variable inside a method it becomes local meaning it's only visible in that method, that is why you are getting that error, you can correct that by making it global.